# Host a serverless contact page using Amazon Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, contact-form, amazon-gateway

I want to host a serverless contact page on Amazon Cloudfront.

I've followed this tutorial to the tee:
[Processing a Contact Form Using AWS Cloudfront...](https://www.codeengine.com/articles/process-form-aws-api-gateway-lambda/)

There are many steps, but the most important things that I would like to highlight that I have done correctly:

- I have set the AWS S3 bucket to public, and given public read access
- My Cloudfront behavior allows the POST method (which I use in my HTML contact-form and corresponding js)
- My Lambda function and my API Gateway send an e-mail to me (so I know that is working!)

Still, when I press submit on my actual website, I get this error:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.

[image: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.]

Could anyone please suggest to me where I might be going wrong? The website contact form is [here](https://xtinapark.com/contact.html).

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption this is a website endpoint the following appears in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff).

> Requests supported: Supports only GET and HEAD requests on objects

It looks as though this is not supported for static websites and instead will need to be worked around.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response Chris! Like I said in my second bullet, I had already addressed this so I know it's not the problem :( Thank you though, it was a good possibility to troubleshoot.

Comment: It looks like this was changed in 2013, so it should accept POST now:
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2013/10/15/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-put-post-and-other-http-methods/#:~:text=We%20are%20excited%20to%20announce,%2C%20DELETE%2C%20OPTIONS%20and%20PATCH.

Comment: That links for CloudFront, it’s the S3 bucket returning the error. You can reproduce this by calling the S3 website endpoint :)

Comment: Ahhh, but I am using a REST API endpoint using API Gateway

Comment: The error message that’s returned in the screenshot is an S3 error. You can tell as the ResourceType is object :)

Comment: The document you linked to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff shows that if it's an XML-formatted error response, which mine is, then it is a REST endpoint error. 

I am probably missing something, and appreciate your help! What do you think a work-around would be?

Comment: You could use an AJAX response to try and post directly to API Gateway rather than posting to what might resolve to an S3 object. You should give that a test first generating  a post request using postman (or similar tool) to ensure it works